# Foreach in controller in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-5

I want to $selected_student in foreach in selecct query should select all column with all respected student_id and then display datatable (It is not doing same and giving errors).

I am using yajra datatable.

controller

```
public function anyData(Request $request)
{
    $selected_batch_value = Session::get('batch_selection');

    $select_student = DB::table('student_batch')
      ->select('student_id')
      ->where('batch_id', '=', $selected_batch_value)
      ->get();

    if($selected_batch_value != 0) {  
        foreach($select_student as $select_student) {         
            $student[] = student::select('student_id', 'first_name','middle_name','last_name', \DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ",middle_name, " " ,last_name) AS full_name'), 'mobile_num', 'email','address_line1','address_line2','state','city','pincode',\DB::raw('CONCAT(address_line1, "<br>",address_line2, "<br> " ,state, "<br>",city,"<br>",pincode) AS address'))
            ->where('student_id', '=', $select_student->id)
            ->get();                  
        }

        return Datatables::of($student)->make(true);
    } else {
        $student = student::select('student_id', 'first_name','middle_name','last_name', \DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ",middle_name, " " ,last_name) AS full_name'), 'mobile_num', 'email','address_line1','address_line2','state','city','pincode',\DB::raw('CONCAT(address_line1, "<br>",address_line2, "<br> " ,state, "<br>",city,"<br>",pincode) AS address'));

        return Datatables::of($student)->make(true);
    }      
}
```

Comment: `foreach($select_student as $select_student)` what? It's stupid, please read any article about `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

The error is in your `foreach` loop,

This is the structure or `foreach` loop,

```
foreach ($variable as $key => $value){
 # code...
}
```

In your case the `$variable` and `$value` are same, both are `$select_student`. change it to,

```
foreach($select_student as $value){
$student[] = student::select('student_id', 'first_name','middle_name','last_name', \DB::raw('CONCAT(first_name, " ",middle_name, " " ,last_name) AS full_name'), 'mobile_num', 'email','address_line1','address_line2','state','city','pincode',\DB::raw('CONCAT(address_line1, "<br>",address_line2, "<br> " ,state, "<br>",city,"<br>",pincode) AS address'))
      ->where('student_id', '=', $value->id)
      ->get();
}
```